# Remote Desktop Web Connection

Tags: iis, remote-desktop, rdp, terminal-services

I understand pretty well that Windows RDP works on TCP port 3389, I came across Remote Desktop Web Connection feature in IIS that adds tsweb access, my question is, does Remote Desktop Web Connection use http protocol as a transport protocol over port 80? Or is tsweb just an ActiveX control that acts as an rdp client and connects normally to 3389?

Answer (score 3):

Windows Remote Desktop Services (RDS) role have a IIS feature called "[Remote Desktop Gateway](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_Desktop_Services#Remote_Desktop_Gateway)". This gateway makes the TSWeb ActiveX to tunnel the RDP session through an HTTPS channel (port 443) instead of having it acting as an RDP client (using the mstsc COM object probably) on port 3389.

If you don't mind trying an open source alternative, written in C# (.NET) and also using a IIS gateway (but not the RDS one), without any plugin browser side (and working in all browsers, HTML 4 and 5), I released recently [Myrtille](http://cedrozor.github.io/myrtille).

Answer (score 0):

The Remote Desktop Web Access role (formerly Terminal Services Web Access) installs a website on a Windows Server machine. "TSWeb" is a website : you access it using the http protocol.

If you access this website with Internet Explorer, IE will ask you if you want to download an ActiveX. This ActiveX will allow you to connect to remote machines via port 3389 (RDP). However, "TS Web Access" **itself** is not an activeX, it is a website **containing** an activeX.

FYI, other browsers do not support activeX objects. On such browsers, the "TSweb" website will make you download a .RDP file instead of launching a remote connection via the activeX. When you double click on this file, or launch it with Remote desktop client, the remote connection is established via port 3389.